# Как расшифровать кусок логфайла?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon, amazon-web-services, odoo

Запускаю Odoo 9 на Ubuntu Server 14.04 на сервере AWS.

На данный момент выполнена установка Odoo, PostgreSQL, python и т.п. ([согласно инструкции](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-odoo-9-erp-on-ubuntu-14-04)).

Судя по записям в логе, Odoo запущена? Но при входе на `http://<your_domain_or_IP_address>:8069` выходит ошибка и пустая страница.

Что говорит данный кусок лога?

> 2016-01-29 13:02:41,569 1167 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
>   2016-01-29 13:02:41,570 1167 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']
>   2016-01-29 13:02:41,570 1167 INFO ? openerp: database: odoo@default:default
>   2016-01-29 13:02:41,803 1167 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069

Comment: В данном куске лога нет информации об ошибке. Он говорит только что вы запустили OpenERP *version 9.0c*. При этом все addons разположены в след. директориях `['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']`. используете дефолтную базу. А сам сервер вертится на `http://0.0.0.0:8069`. Приведите текст ошибки, чтобы было проще вам помочь.

Comment: Ваш комментарий является ответом на вопрос. Ранее я не мог зайти на odoo через браузер, потому что не открыл порт 8069. Спасибо.